# How to use translate3d and a scale on the same element?

Tags: css, transform, css-animations, translate

I have to vertically flip some elements for Right to Left (rtl) languages. Problem is that the elements are being animated in using a translate3d.

### **QUESTION:**

**How can I vertically flip an element using:**

```
-moz-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-webkit-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-o-transform: scale(-1, 1);
-ms-transform: scale(-1, 1);
transform: scale(-1, 1);
```

**But leave this snippet in tact?**

```
.vertical-carousel-item{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
}
```

Comment: It isnt a duplicate.  Transition are different than Transforms.

Comment: Yeah, CV retracted; I was thinking of transition and translate, not transform and translate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in the same class, you can do it like:

```
.vertical-carousel-item{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
}
```

Otherwise, you will leave the class as is, and just add the `scale()` property like:

```
.vertical-carousel-item{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    -o-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
    transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0);
}
.vertical-carousel-item.someOtherClass{
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -ms-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    -o-transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
    transform: translate3d(75px,-55px,0) scale(-1, 1);
}
```